# How can I load an Image using Opencv and pass it to Unity (through a C++ dll)?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine

### CONTEXT

I am currently using [opencv](https://opencv.org/) to detect some pattern in a video feed and send that information to a Unity game. 
I have found [Aruco](https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26), a opencv module and both  [ArucoUnity](https://github.com/NormandErwan/ArucoUnity)  and [ArucoUnityPlugin](https://github.com/NormandErwan/ArucoUnityPlugin). But it doesn't fit my requirements so I am currently remaking a simpler version (e.i. making a dll using opencv as a lib and importing its function in Unity).

### ISSUE

While with simple parameters (int, string) and manage to get the values back, I am struggling to load images into Mat (through the imread function) and getting the Mat back in C#. I can create a empty Mat() using new Mat() and get it back into C#, I can load my imagetest into a Mat, but when I try to put it into the Mat that I return, the application crashes.

### CODE

**C++**

mat.hpp (part of)

```
#ifdef PATTERNRECOGNITIONTOCLONEDLL_EXPORTS
#define PATTERNRECOGNITION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PATTERNRECOGNITION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" {
    const string pluginFolderPath = "./Assets/Plugin/";

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API cv::Mat* mat_new();
    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API cv::Mat* mat_loadPath(const char* path);
}
```

mat.cpp (part of)

```
cv::Mat* mat_new() // This works
{
    return new cv::Mat();
}

cv::Mat* mat_loadPath(const char* path) // This doesn't
{
    Mat* matPtr = new cv::Mat(); // Create an empty Mat
    *matPtr = cv::imread(pluginFolderPath + string(path), cv::IMREAD_COLOR); // read the image into the Mat
    return matPtr;
}
```

**C#**

Mat.cs (part of)

```
class Mat : HandleCppPtr
{
    public Mat(string path) : base(mat_loadPath(path))
    {
    }
    public Mat() : base(mat_new())
    {
    }
}
```

HandleCppPtr.cs (part of)

```
public enum DeleteResponsibility
{
    True,
    False
}

public abstract class  HandleCppPtr
{

    public HandleCppPtr(IntPtr cppPtr, DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility = DeleteResponsibility.True)
    {
        CppPtr = cppPtr;
        this.deleteResponsibility = deleteResponsibility;
    }

    ~HandleCppPtr()
    {
        if(this.deleteResponsibility == DeleteResponsibility.True)
        {
            Debug.Log("[C# ]Deleting HandleCppPtr object -> " + this.ToString());
            DeleteCppPtr();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("[C# ] NOT Deleting HandleCppPtr object because deleteResp is False -> " + this.ToString());
        }
    }

    public IntPtr CppPtr
    {
        get { return handle.Handle; }
        set { handle = new HandleRef(this, value); }
    }
    public DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility;
    HandleRef handle;
    protected abstract void DeleteCppPtr();
}
```

### ERROR

When I try to create a the Mat using this following C# code :

```
void Update()
{
    string testImagePath = "TestMatImage.png";
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        Debug.Log("[C# ] Loading Image by Path = " + testImagePath);
        Mat mat = new Mat(testImagePath);
        Debug.Log(mat.ToString());
    }
}
```

it crashes and I get the following error :
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!
Program:

This application has requested the Runtime to termintate in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN0Xb.png)

### EDIT 1

I have tried printing pointers to see if no shenanigans were happennings when using imread but the value (while changing between restarts) is the same before and after. So it doesn't seems to be that.
Still here the code I used.

```
cv::Mat* mat_loadPath(const char* path)
{
    string message = "[C++] Loading mat by Path -> " + pluginFolderPath + string(path);
    DebugLog(message.c_str()); // Custom function that send debug message to Unity
    // PRINT : [C++] Loading mat by Path -> ./Assets/Plugin/TestMatImage.png
    
    Mat* matPtr = new cv::Mat(); // Create an empty Mat
    message = "[C++] Mat Not Loaded -> at " + std::to_string((int)matPtr) + "  (" + std::to_string(matPtr->rows) + "," + std::to_string(matPtr->cols) + ") ";
    DebugLog(message.c_str());
    // PRINT: [C++] Mat Not Loaded -> at -1895966160  (0,0) 

    *matPtr = cv::imread(pluginFolderPath + string(path), cv::IMREAD_COLOR); // read the image into the Mat
     message = "[C++] Mat Loaded -> at "+ std::to_string((int)matPtr) +"  (" + std::to_string(matPtr->rows) + "," + std::to_string(matPtr->cols) + ") " + std::to_string(matPtr->at<Vec3b>(0, 0).val[1]);
    DebugLog(message.c_str());
    // PRINT: [C++] Mat Loaded -> at -1895966160  (10,10) 231
        
    return new cv::Mat(); // If this is replaced by matPtr, the call of the 
}
```

Comment: If you need OpenCV in C#, you can use Emgu : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page This simplifies the C++ wrapping part.

Comment: Thanks Sdra, I am not sure it works as I already done most of my image analyse in C++ (and only sending the results to the C#/Unity side). For what I understand, Emgu is allowing the C# to call opencv's function, which mean I'd have to port all those analyses to the C# side. (+ I'd have to convince people to buy the license)
I would have hope to be able for the Matrix call to work, but I'll look into Emgu code to see if they do something similar and if they do, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the crash which was later on when I wanted to get the values which I casted as the wrong type of values (Vecd instead of the correct Vec3b).
Additionally, I was also not using "new cv::Mat()" when testing and that cause the Mat to be discarded by the C++ (and the C# pointing to random stuff).

For anyone that would like to do something similare here is my code (even if it' is heavily inspired by ArucoUnity/ArucoUnityPlugin by NormandErwan).

### C++

With the following somewhere (for me it was in PatternRecognition.hpp)

```
#ifdef PATTERNRECOGNITIONTOCLONEDLL_EXPORTS
#define PATTERNRECOGNITION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PATTERNRECOGNITION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

mat.hpp

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include "PatternRecognition.hpp"


using namespace CloneToTangible;

extern "C" {

    const string pluginFolderPath = "./Assets/Plugin/";

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API cv::Mat* mat_new();
    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API cv::Mat* mat_loadPath(const char* path);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API void mat_delete(cv::Mat* matPtr);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API Vec3b* mat_at(cv::Mat* mat, uint posX, uint posY);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API int mat_rows(cv::Mat* mat);
    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API int mat_cols(cv::Mat* mat);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API int mat_type(cv::Mat* mat);
}
```

mat.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "mat.hpp"
#include <opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp>

cv::Mat* mat_new()
{
    Mat* matPtr = new cv::Mat();
    //DebugLog(("[C++] Mat Loaded -> at " + std::to_string((int)matPtr) + "  (" + std::to_string(matPtr->rows) + "," + std::to_string(matPtr->cols) + ") " + std::to_string(matPtr->at<Vec3b>(0, 0).val[1])).c_str());
    return matPtr;
}

cv::Mat* mat_loadPath(const char* path)
{
    //DebugLog(("[C++] Loading mat by Path -> " + pluginFolderPath + string(path)).c_str());
    Mat* matPtr = new cv::Mat();
    *matPtr = cv::imread(pluginFolderPath + string(path), cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    //DebugLog(("[C++] Mat Loaded -> at " + std::to_string((int)matPtr) + "  (" + std::to_string(matPtr->rows) + "," + std::to_string(matPtr->cols) + ") " + std::to_string(matPtr->at<Vec3b>(0, 0).val[1])).c_str());
    return matPtr;
}

void mat_delete(cv::Mat* matPtr)
{
    delete matPtr;
}

Vec3b* mat_at(cv::Mat* mat, uint posX, uint posY)
{
    return new Vec3b(mat->at<Vec3b>(posX,posY));
}

int mat_rows(cv::Mat* mat)
{
    //DebugLog(("Returning rows for " + std::to_string((int)&mat) + " which is " + std::to_string(mat->rows)).c_str());
    return mat->rows;
}

int mat_cols(cv::Mat* mat)
{
    //DebugLog(("Returning cols for " + std::to_string((int)&mat) + " which is " + std::to_string(mat->cols)).c_str());
    return mat->cols;
}

int mat_type(cv::Mat* mat)
{
    return mat->type();
}
```

vec3b.hpp

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include "PatternRecognition.hpp"

extern "C" {

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API cv::Vec3b* cv_Vec3b_new(unsigned char v0, unsigned char v1, unsigned char v2);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API void cv_Vec3b_delete(cv::Vec3b* vec3dPtr);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API unsigned char cv_Vec3b_get(cv::Vec3b* vec3dPtr, int i);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API void cv_Vec3b_set(cv::Vec3b* vec3dPtr, int i, unsigned char value);

    PATTERNRECOGNITION_API void cv_Vec3b_setAll(cv::Vec3b* vec3dPtr, unsigned char v0, unsigned char v1, unsigned char v2);;
}
```

vec3b.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "vec3b.hpp"

cv::Vec3b* cv_Vec3b_new(unsigned char v0, unsigned char v1, unsigned char v2)
{
    return new cv::Vec3b(v0, v1, v2);
}

void cv_Vec3b_delete(cv::Vec3b* vec3bPtr)
{
    int n = (*vec3bPtr)[0];
    delete vec3bPtr;
}

unsigned char cv_Vec3b_get(cv::Vec3b* vec3bPtr, int i)
{
    unsigned char value = 0;
    try {
        value = (*vec3bPtr)[i];
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}

void cv_Vec3b_set(cv::Vec3b* vec3bPtr, int i, unsigned char value)
{
    try {
        (*vec3bPtr)[i] = value;
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
    }
}

void cv_Vec3b_setAll(cv::Vec3b* vec3bPtr, unsigned char v0, unsigned char v1, unsigned char v2)
{
    try {
        (*vec3bPtr)[0] = v0;
        (*vec3bPtr)[1] = v1;
        (*vec3bPtr)[2] = v2;
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
    }
}
```

### C#

Mat.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

class Mat : HandleCppPtr
{
    public int cols
    {
        get { return mat_cols(CppPtr); }
    }
    public int rows
    {
        get { return mat_rows(CppPtr); }
    }
    public int type
    {
        get { return mat_type(CppPtr); }
    }

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern IntPtr mat_new();

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    public static extern IntPtr mat_loadPath(string path);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern void mat_delete(IntPtr matPtr);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern IntPtr mat_at(IntPtr matPtr, uint x, uint y);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern int mat_cols(IntPtr matPtr);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern int mat_rows(IntPtr matPtr);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern int mat_type(IntPtr matPtr);

    public Mat(string path, DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility = DeleteResponsibility.True) : base(mat_loadPath(path), deleteResponsibility)
    {
        Debug.Log("[C#] Mat Instantiation : Mat(string path) ");
    }

    public Mat(DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility = DeleteResponsibility.True) : base(mat_new(), deleteResponsibility)
    {
        Debug.Log("[C#] Mat Instantiation : Mat() ");
    }
    public Mat(IntPtr cppPtr, DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility = DeleteResponsibility.True) : base(cppPtr, deleteResponsibility)
    {

    }

    public Vec3b At(uint x, uint y)
    {
        if (x < rows && y < cols)
            return new Vec3b(mat_at(this.CppPtr, x, y));
        else
            return new Vec3b();
    }

    protected override void DeleteCppPtr()
    {
        //Debug.Log("[C#] Mat Destruction : DeleteCppPtr(), before mat_delete() call ");
        mat_delete(this.CppPtr);
        //Debug.Log("[C#] Mat Destruction : DeleteCppPtr(), after mat_delete() call ");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string message = "Mat->";
        int rows = mat_rows(this.CppPtr);
        Debug.Log("[C#] Mat has " + rows + " rows");
        int cols = mat_cols(this.CppPtr);
        Debug.Log("[C#] Mat has " + cols + " cols");
        for (uint x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            message += "\n {";
            for (uint y = 0; y < cols; y++)
            {
                message += At(x, y).ToString();
            }
            message += "}";
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

Vec3b.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Vec3b : HandleCppPtr
{

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern IntPtr cv_Vec3b_new(byte v0, byte v1, byte v2);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern void cv_Vec3b_delete(IntPtr vec3bPtr);


    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern byte cv_Vec3b_get(IntPtr vec3bPtr, int i);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern void cv_Vec3b_set(IntPtr vec3bPtr, int i, byte value);

    [DllImport("PatternRecognitionToCloneDLL")]
    static extern void cv_Vec3b_setAll(IntPtr vec3bPtr, byte v0, byte v1, byte v2);

    public Vec3b(byte v0 = 0, byte v1 = 0, byte v2 = 0) : base(cv_Vec3b_new(v0, v1, v2))
    {
    }

    public Vec3b(IntPtr cppPtr) : base(cppPtr)
    {
    }

    protected override void DeleteCppPtr()
    {
        cv_Vec3b_delete(this.CppPtr);
    }

    public int Get(int i)
    {
        return cv_Vec3b_get(this.CppPtr, i);
    }

    public void Set(int i, byte value)
    {
        cv_Vec3b_set(this.CppPtr, i, value);
    }


    public void Set(byte v0, byte v1, byte v2)
    {
        cv_Vec3b_setAll(this.CppPtr, v0, v1, v2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string message = "Vec3b->";
        message += "(" + Get(0) + "," + Get(1) + "," + Get(2) + ")";
        return message;
    }

}
```

HandleCppPtr.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;


public enum DeleteResponsibility
{
    True,
    False
}
public abstract class  HandleCppPtr
{

    public HandleCppPtr(IntPtr cppPtr, DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility = DeleteResponsibility.True)
    {
        CppPtr = cppPtr;
        this.deleteResponsibility = deleteResponsibility;
    }

    ~HandleCppPtr()
    {
        if(this.deleteResponsibility == DeleteResponsibility.True)
        {
            //Debug.Log("[C# ]Deleting HandleCppPtr object -> " + this.ToString());
            DeleteCppPtr();
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("[C# ] NOT Deleting HandleCppPtr object because deleteResp is False -> " + this.ToString());
        }
    }

    public IntPtr CppPtr
    {
        get { return handle.Handle; }
        set { handle = new HandleRef(this, value); }
    }
    public DeleteResponsibility deleteResponsibility;
    HandleRef handle;
    protected abstract void DeleteCppPtr();
}
```